# Trigger all buttons of the same Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid in which I have a series of buttons (made using the ASP.Net MVC helper) that send Ajax requests. However I have also added a master button to trigger all buttons implemented in the grid. All my Ajax button have the same ID. However when I use the `trigger` method like

```
$("#myBtn").trigger("click")
```

only the first button is triggered. Is it possible to trigger all buttons with the same id using a similar approach?

Comment: No, it's not possible, because **ID's are unique**, you can only use an ID *(unique identifier)* once in the same document

Comment: id can only be unique among elements. Use class instead. Assign class="myBtn" and then use `$('.myBtn')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of the attribute `id` should be unique. The same `id` value cannot be assigned to different elements. Selector by `id` returns a single element. Use `class` selector instead

```
$(".myBtn").trigger("click")
```

Answer (score 4):

Not recommended since `id` should be unique, but you can do this to trigger the click action on all elements with `id` `myBtn`:

```
$('[id=myBtn]').trigger('click');
```